# how to combine both DISPLAY_NAME and NUMBER in a customized CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, contacts, autocompletetextview

I want to load all of my contacts' names and phone numbers into an AutoCompleteTextView's adapter. How can I achieve that? for example, when i type "G", it will show "Good, <111111>", "Good, <222222>" in its drop-down list.

with the api demo, i can only put the DISPLAY_NAMEs in the result cursor. I don't know how to combine both names and numbers into one cursor. thanks!

codes from the api demo:

```
ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = content.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,  
    PEOPLE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, cursor);
mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

private static class ContactListAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {  
    private ContentResolver mCR;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {  
        super(context, c);  
        mCR = context.getContentResolver();  
    }  

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
        view.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {  
        ((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(1));
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {  
        return cursor.getString(1);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
            return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
        }
        StringBuilder buffer = null;
        String[] args = null;
        if (constraint != null) {
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
            buffer.append("UPPER(");
            buffer.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
            args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
        }
        return mCR.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PEOPLE_PROJECTION,
                buffer == null ? null : buffer.toString(), args, null);
    }
}

private static final String[] PEOPLE_PROJECTION = new String[] {  
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers should already be part of the cursor.  Retrieve them like so.

```
final long phoneNumber;// = c.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER_KEY);
        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){
            id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME);
            int numberKeyColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER_KEY);             
            phoneNumber = this.getPhoneNumbers(id); }
```

Then the getPhoneNumbers method, in the same class, unforunately has to iterate again.  Not sure if there's a better way to do this by binding to a cursor (in the new api), but it works.

```
        public Long getPhoneNumbers(String id) {
        Long number = new Long(0);
        ContentResolver cr = this.context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                new String[]{id}, null);
        pCur.moveToFirst();
        if (pCur.getCount() > 0){
            String num = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            num = num.replaceAll("-", "");
            number = Long.parseLong(num);
        }
        pCur.close();
        return number;
    }
```