# AlphabetIndexer not working with Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, indexing, customization

I am using AlphabetIndexer, SectionIndexer, Custom CursorAdapter for a Customized ListView. following is the code for the same. But I am not able to see the Alphabets while scrolling the List. I also tried the following link [how to combine both DISPLAY_NAME and NUMBER in a customized CursorAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358106/how-to-combine-both-display-name-and-number-in-a-customized-cursoradapter)

```
public class ContactListCustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements
    SectionIndexer {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private CursorsForContacts cursorsForContacts;
private AlphabetIndexer alphabetIndexer;

public ContactListCustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, true);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    cursorsForContacts = new CursorsForContacts(context);
    alphabetIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(
            cursor,
            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME),
            " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    //alphabetIndexer.setCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    String contactId = setContactName(view, cursor);
    setContactPhoneNumbers(view, contactId);
    setContactEmails(view, contactId);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_contact_list_item,
            parent, false);

    return view;
}

private String setContactName(View view, Cursor cursor) {
    int username = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    TextView userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userName.setText(cursor.getString(username));

    return cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

}

private void setContactPhoneNumbers(View view, String contactId) {
    Cursor phoneCursor = cursorsForContacts.getPhoneNumberCursor(contactId);
    TextView phoneNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userNumber);
    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
        phoneNumber
                .setText(phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
    }
}

private void setContactEmails(View view, String contactId) {
    Cursor emailCursor = cursorsForContacts.getEmailCursor(contactId);
    TextView userEmailId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userEmailId);
    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
        userEmailId
                .setText(emailCursor.getString(emailCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));
    }
}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    return alphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return alphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    return alphabetIndexer.getSections();
}

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

Comment: @Nik The same here.. Have you found anything on that? cause my searching has reached an end with no success..

Comment: Have you tried this [tutorial](https://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` to the ListView in your layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for OP but other folks who stumble here with the same question might benefit...

In my case alphabet indexer was "randomly" there in some instances and not there on the same screen in others.

Turns out if the list is not very long, fast scroll and thus alphabet indexer will be suspended. The exact behavior can be found in class [`FastScroller`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/FastScroller.java) which is a helper class for `AbsListView`. There is a piece of code there that decides if "the list is long"

```
final boolean longList = childCount > 0 && itemCount / childCount >= MIN_PAGES;
```

`MIN_PAGES` is defined with value of 4. There you have it, if your list item count is not at least 4x the child count (visible rows) fast scroller and thus alphabet indexer will not appear.